# iOS Way the Checkmark disappears when begin scroll down

Tags: ios, uitableview

Way the Checkmark disappears when begin scroll down.

Heres the code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        if ([[[collectionDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"creditHours"]==@"1") {
            totalHoure = totalHoure - 1;
        }

    } else {

        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        if ([[[collectionDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"creditHours"]==@"1") {
            totalHoure = totalHoure + 1 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any problem ? or if there any other technique.

Comment: Show the code you have in **`viewWillAppear:`**. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` has nothing to do with scrolling. Also, you should be assigning the checkmark accessory in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `. If you want to toggle checkmarks, place `reloadData` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to store checkmark cell data.And hope this solves your problem:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone || [selectedCell accessoryType]== UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)   
       {
           [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                    [Mybuffer addObject:[arrItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       }
       else
       {
           [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
           [Mybuffer removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
       }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code a bit, to make it more readable. Also, could you explain in a line or two what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to store the checkmark in your model somewhere. Cells are recreated on the fly as the user scrolls the `UITableView`. Then make sure to re-set the checkmark correctly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.